# App version different response

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I check the version on AppStore an display a proper message for update.
   
The problem is that the same URL `http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=my_app_bundle` i call in Postman and also in app like this:

```
- (void)checkForNewVersion
{
    appIsLastVersion = YES;

    NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    NSString *currentAppVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

    NSString *appInfoUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@", bundleIdentifier];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appInfoUrl]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLSession *sesion = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
   NSURLSessionDataTask *task =  [sesion dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSError *e = nil;
        NSData *jsonData = [output dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

        NSArray *results = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"results"];
        if (results.count > 0) {
            NSString *version = [[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"version"];
            appIsLastVersion = [version isEqualToString:currentAppVersion];

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];

    [task resume];
}
```

i receive 2 different response on Postman:

```
"currentVersionReleaseDate": "2017-03-15T23:14:08Z"
"version": "2.0.1"
```

and on app

```
currentVersionReleaseDate = "2017-03-13T07:37:19Z"
version = "2.0.0"
```

Any solution ?

Comment: For me also this issue is happen. You need to wait at least one day for apple server to sync your new app version details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the main reason is that the data was cached so i changed the `NSURLSession`:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;

NSURLSession *sesion = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24329317/2050181)