# How long does URLSession dataTask cache my server's data?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

This is my first app and I'm wondering if I have made a mistake with regards to using URLSession.shared dataTask because I am not seeing my app get new data which is frequently updated.  I see the new json instantly in my browser when I refresh, but, my app apparently does not see it.

Will it ever get the new json data from my server without uninstalling the app?

*There are some some similar question topics, such as [How to disable caching from NSURLSessionTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328461/how-to-disable-caching-from-nsurlsessiontask) however, I do not want to disable all caching.  Instead, I want to know how this default object behaves in this scenario - How long is it going to cache it?  If indeed the answer is forever, or until they update or reinstall the app, then I will want to know how to reproduce the normal browser based cache behavior, using if-modified-since header, but that is not my question here.*

I call my download() function below gratuitously after the launch sequence.

```
func download(_ ch: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ respone: URLResponse?, _ error: Error?) -> (), completionHandler: @escaping (_ sessionError: Error?) -> ()) {

    let myFileURL: URL? = getFileURL(filename: self.getFilename(self.jsonTestName))

    let myTestURL = URL(string:getURLString(jsonTestName))
    let session = URLSession.shared

    // now we call dataTask and we see a CH and it calls My CH

    let task = session.dataTask(with: myTestURL!) { (data, response, error) // generic CH for dataTask
        in

        // my special CH
        ch(data,response,error)  // make sure the file gets written in this ch
    }
    task.resume()  // no such thing as status in async here
}
```

Within the completion handler which I pass to download, I save the data with this code from "ch":

```
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    let documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: myFileURL!)
                    documentController.delegate = self as UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

                }
```

and then finally, I read the data within that same completion handler from disk as such:

```
 let data = try Data(contentsOf: myFileURL!)
```

For clarification, my complete calling function from which I call download() with completion handler code.

```
  func get_test(){ // download new tests
    let t = testOrganizer
    let myFileURL: URL? = t.getFileURL(filename:t.getFilename(t.jsonTestName))

    t.download( { (data,response,error)
        in
        var status: Int! = 0
        status = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode
        if(status == nil) {
            status = 0
        }
        if(error != nil || (status != 200 && status != 304)) {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error downloading", message:"Could not download updated test data.  HTTP Status: \(status!)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.p.print("END OF COMPLETION HANDLER")
        }
        else {
            let status = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode

            print("Success: status = ", status)

            self.p.print("WRITING FILE IN COMPLETION HANDLER")

            do {
                try data!.write(to: myFileURL!)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    let documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: myFileURL!)
                    documentController.delegate = self as UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

                }

            } catch {
               // // _ = completionHandler(NSError(domain:"Write failed", code:190, userInfo:nil))
                print("error writing file \(myFileURL!) : \(error)")
            }

            self.myJson = self.testOrganizer.readJson()

            self.p.print("END OF COMPLETION HANDLER")

        }
        }, completionHandler: {
        sessionError in
        if(sessionError == nil) {
            print("Downloaded and saved file successfully")
        } else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "get_tests", message:
                "Failed to download new tests - " + sessionError.debugDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code together , you have shown it in parts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable caching from NSURLSessionTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328461/how-to-disable-caching-from-nsurlsessiontask)

Comment: Sure thing, here is the complete call with completion handler code that calls the download function above.