# Why did I need to set the cache policy on the URLRequest when it was already set on the URLSession to avoid caching?

Tags: ios, url, urlsession, urlrequest

I am building an iOS app that needs to frequently check for changes to a JSON file on my server. In the process of doing this I discovered a quirk with caching. My server is running a very basic [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) for now as I get things off the ground.

When I realized caching was preventing my clients from writing At first I wrote the code:

```
let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
func updateModel() {
  let (data, _) = try await urlSession.data(from: URL(string: myURLString)!)
  // Do something with the data
}
```

Which was suggested in the [Apple developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/716620).

This did not work so I went a step further trying this

```
let urlSession =  {
    var session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
    session.configuration.urlCache = nil
    session.configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    return session
}()
func updateModel() {
  let (data, _) = try await urlSession.data(from: URL(string: myURLString)!)
  // Do something with the data
}
```

This approach was suggested in a [Stack Overflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42722401/3833632). Worth noting people in the comments mentioning it didn't work for them or they needed to call `URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()` which isn't ideal. I didn't want to do that call and this code was not working for me so I went onto something much heavier handed.

```
let urlSession =  {
    var session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
    session.configuration.urlCache = nil
    session.configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    return session
}()
func updateModel() {
  let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: myURLString)!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData)
  let (data, _) = try await urlSession.data(for: request)
  // Do something with the data
}
```

Which I don't know precisely where I got the idea to try from.

So I guest. Yay! It works. But also... why was all this necessary? Why did I need to nix the cache both at the URLSession AND at the URLRequest level? Does it have to do with my use of a string URL, maybe the way my server is vending resources, maybe iOS 17, the content type I am vending. I would like to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

Let us see the func we called.

```
extension URLSession {

    public func data(for request: URLRequest, delegate: (URLSessionTaskDelegate)? = nil) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse)

    public func data(from url: URL, delegate: (URLSessionTaskDelegate)? = nil) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse)
}
```

```
public struct URLRequest : ReferenceConvertible, Equatable, Hashable, Sendable {

    public init(url: URL, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: TimeInterval = 60.0)
}
```

For the second func of `URLSession`, its implementation may be

```
public func data(from url: URL, delegate: (URLSessionTaskDelegate)? = nil) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    return self.data(from: request)
}
```

you guess what? the `URLRequest`'s `cachePolicy` is set default to useProtocolCachePolicy.

So that's what your problem comes.